# User info for attributes in Core Data Model disappear

Tags: xcode, core-data

Whenever I close XCode, the User Info entries that I set for attributes in my Core Data models simply disappear. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this still applies: 
Simply on the CoreData editor select the data model you are working on and on the File Inspector change the Tool version to the latest one. 
Problem solved!

I actually posted about this issue on my blog. Here is the [link](http://twoshotsofcocoa.com/?p=51).

Comment: your link is broken